# Como fazer uma página em html começar em uma determinada posição?

Tags: html

Qunado eu entrar na minha página o focu dela não ficar no topo mas sim no meio por exemplo, é possível?

Comment: Como assim? Poderia dar exemplos concretos?

Comment: Tipo quando eu entrar na página, eu gostaria que ela nn começa-se do topo entende?

Comment: Seria tipo ir para uma seção específica?

Comment: quando eu clicasse em um link

Comment: É possível, mas há diversas maneiras de fazer que dependem do que exatamente você precisa. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e adicionar um [mcve], composto por algum trecho de código, que reproduza o que você quer fazer? Há maneiras de mover a página até certo elemento, ou até certa altura da página, mas não está claro o que você precisa. Algo como "tenho essa página, quero que ele comece aqui..." é essencial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tudo bem Vinicius?

Você pode utilizar o método de ancoragem!
Se você tem uma ID do local exato que você quer levar o usuário, é só ancorar ela desta forma:

```
<a href="#topo">LINK</a>
<div id="topo">
CONTEUDO
</div>
```

No caso a função < a > irá ancorar para levar o usuário a uma parte específica da página.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Você deseja que o scroll já inicie em uma certa posição.

O trecho deve funcionar: `window.scrollTo(0,150)`

Para chama-lo no início da execução utilize:

```
window.onload = function(){
     window.scrollTo(0,150)
}
```

Fiz um exemplo de funcionamento: https://codepen.io/xstarman/pen/maewxP

Isso fará que ao carregar, o scroll desça para 150px

> https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollTo

Answer (score 0):

Se você quer que a sua página abra em algum ponto específico, bastar fazer referência ao id do local onde você deseja iniciar.

```
http://www.paginaexemplo.com/pagina.html#id
```

onde o #id é referente ao id dentro da sua página html.

Exemplo:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/349706/como-fazer-uma-p%c3%a1gina-em-html-come%c3%a7ar-em-uma-determinada-posi%c3%a7%c3%a3o#answer-349713
```

Cole a URL acima no navegador e ele irá abrir a página diretamente na minha resposta, pois o id answer-349713 é referente a minha resposta.